# Spring MVC Hibernate Many to One is giving null value for the foreign key

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller, mapping, many-to-one

I need some help on Spring MVC 4  and hibernate 5 (both latest version as at now).

I have two classes -- Member and Family. Member(Staff) can have multiple family members that 
I would like to have Many-to-one relation with Family class.

Snapp shot of the Member class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "member")
public class Member {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "member_id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;


    private String firstName;

    private String middleName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="member")
    private List<Family> families;

    .....

    }
```

The snapshot of the Family class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="family")
public class Family {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String email;
    private String mobile;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
    private Member member;

    ----

    }
```

Controllers:

```
`@RequestMapping("/admin/memberManagement/addMember")
    public ModelAndView addMember(@ModelAttribute("member") Member member) {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("addMember");
        return view;
    }


      @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/memberManagement/addMember", method =     RequestMethod.POST)

       public ModelAndView addMemberPost(@ModelAttribute("member") Member member, Model model) {    
        memberService.addMember(member);
            ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin/memberManagement");
        return view;
    }`
```

The form has one Member with list of corresponding families (fields added dynamically), and when I run the programme, it saves the Member with no problem, and it saves the list of families as well, but with null value for member_id in family table.

what I have missed here? I appreciate your help.  I am learning Spring MVC.

Thanks,

Maadis.

**Additional information/question **

Following Alexander Staroselsky's answer, I tried few options, but the member_id column in family table is still null.  On the start of the server, it generates the following sql tables and constraints:

```
Hibernate: 

    alter table family 
       drop 
       foreign key FKpv3nain50fsmms2j4xdig4f8u
Hibernate: 

    drop table if exists family
Hibernate: 

    drop table if exists hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: 

    drop table if exists member
Hibernate: 

    create table family (
       id integer not null,
        email varchar(255),
        firstName varchar(255),
        lastName varchar(255),
        mobile varchar(255),
        relation varchar(255),
        member_id integer,
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 

    create table hibernate_sequence (
       next_val bigint
    )
Hibernate: 

    insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
Hibernate: 

    insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
Hibernate: 

    create table member (
       member_id integer not null,
        discharge datetime,
        email varchar(255),
        firstname varchar(255),
        lastname varchar(255),
        middlename varchar(255),
        mobile varchar(255),
        number varchar(255),
        rank varchar(255),
        regiment varchar(255),
        telephone varchar(255),
        website varchar(255),
        primary key (member_id)
    )
Hibernate: 

    alter table family 
       add constraint FKpv3nain50fsmms2j4xdig4f8u 
       foreign key (member_id) 
       references member (member_id)
```

It has created the tables correctly + added the necessary constraint. Is something to do with the hibernate and spring mvc versions? Does anyone encountered this problem?  The version I am using are:

```
<properties>
        <spring.version>4.3.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <security.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</security.version>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.8.0</org.aspectj-version>
        <mysql.connector-version>6.0.5</mysql.connector-version>
        <jackson.databind-version>2.8.5</jackson.databind-version>
        <tiles.version>3.0.7</tiles.version>
    </properties>
```

## Thanks,

Thanks, Alexander, for your time - truly appreciated.  Changing to @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) did not work.  Making member properties to 'nullable=false' does not work as well, this value is actually giving null.  The insert sql statement goes as follows:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        member0_.member_id as member_i1_1_,
        member0_.email as email2_1_,
        member0_.firstname as firstnam3_1_,
        member0_.lastname as lastname4_1_,
        member0_.website as website5_1_ 
    from
        member member0_
Hibernate: 
    select
        next_val as id_val 
    from
        hibernate_sequence for update

Hibernate: 
    update
        hibernate_sequence 
    set
        next_val= ? 
    where
        next_val=?
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        member
        (email, firstname, lastname, website, member_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        family
        (email, firstName, lastName, member_id, mobile) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        family
        (email, firstName, lastName, member_id, mobile) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    select
        member0_.member_id as member_i1_1_,
        member0_.email as email2_1_,
        member0_.firstname as firstnam3_1_,
        member0_.lastname as lastname4_1_,
        member0_.website as website5_1_ 
    from
        member member0_
```

The sql insert looks normal -- all other values are there, except the member_id in family table.

The inserted test values on both tables:

```
mysql> select * from member;
+-----------+----------------+-----------+----------+---------+
| member_id | email          | firstname | lastname | website |
+-----------+----------------+-----------+----------+---------+
|         1 | test@email.com | firstname | lastname | dot.com |
+-----------+----------------+-----------+----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from family;
+----+----------------+-----------+----------+--------+-----------+
| id | email          | firstName | lastName | mobile | member_id |
+----+----------------+-----------+----------+--------+-----------+
|  1 | test@email.com | test1     | test`    | i3i3   |      NULL |
|  2 | test@gmail.com | test2     | test2    | 7373   |      NULL |
+----+----------------+-----------+----------+--------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thanks

## One more testing

I just removed the mappedBy="member" to test if it works in separate table. It works perfectly fine. As expected, it created the third table -- member_family -- and inserted the id values correctly.   The followings are the test values:

```
mysql> select * from member;
+-----------+----------------+-----------+----------+---------+
| member_id | email          | firstname | lastname | website |
+-----------+----------------+-----------+----------+---------+
|         1 | test@email.com | tre       | jjj      | dot.com |
+-----------+----------------+-----------+----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from family;
+----+-----------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+
| id | email           | firstName | lastName | mobile   | member_id |
+----+-----------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+
|  1 | dkdke@email.com | test      | teke     | d8i38303 |      NULL |
|  2 | e@gmai.com      | test1     | testie   | 38383    |      NULL |
+----+-----------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from member_family;
+------------------+-------------+
| Member_member_id | families_id |
+------------------+-------------+
|                1 |           1 |
|                1 |           2 |
+------------------+-------------+
```

Now, the problem seems to be on the mappedBy (something I may have missed) only. Any pointers would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try replace `@GeneratedValue` with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` to ensure an ID is being generated for each object:

```
...
public class Member {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "member_id")
    @GeneratedValue(GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
...

...
public class Family {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String email;
    private String mobile;
...
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexander, for your response.  The  @GeneratedValue(GenerationType.AUTO) provided the autogenerated values for primary keys of member and family, but the member_id column in family table is still null (instead of memberId value. Anything else I can try here? Thanks,

Comment: Try `GenerationType.Identity` (javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY) instead of `GenerationType.AUTO`. Also try adding `unique = true, nullable = false` to the `@Column` params of Member. I don't think this is a hibernate/spring version issue. Can you show the SQL for the inserts of the values?

Comment: Hi Alexander, Thanks for your message.  Changing to these did not work as well.  I have updated my question with SQL insert. Thanks,